# What does badref mean?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

What does that IR line mean

```
define i32 <badref>() {
```

for defining a new function and writing it in the file

Answer (score 5):

Typically you get `<badref>` printed out when the IR is malformed. You should run the [verifier pass](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#verify-module-verifier) on your module to see if it can help you find out what the precise problem is.

In this particular case I'm guessing you have created a new unnamed function but have not yet added it to a module - without a module it cannot number the global values, so it cannot name the function.