# What is the meaning of "badref" in llvm IR?

Tags: compilation, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm wondering what this is telling me. In the first picture you can see IR after one loop pass, whereas in the second one you can see one ordinary pass which executes after and before the loop pass. The problem is, when any loop pass is ran I get this "badref" in the case of load instruction and in case of other passes it doesn't appear. Does anyone have experience with this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, no screenshots full of text here. SO should be found when people google for the text of the error message, hiding the text from google doesn't help. Please edit your question. Badref means that the object being referenced in that location has been deleted, which is always a bug.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177028/what-does-badref-mean. In this case your problem is a value name, whereas in that case it was a function name. But either way, it means it's malformed IR.